# Securing my intranet

Tags: router, wireless, access-point

There are two parts to my question.

First of all, I am a novice networking enthusiast at best. I studied programming in school so I have a technical backbone. However I am  finding myself increasingly lost in the IT world especially when it comes to networking. I want to change that. If anyone can recommend some good resources a beginner can use to crawl out of ignorance I would greatly appreciate it.

Having said that...I am attempting to setup dedicated guest access for our customers at my family business. I have an Asus RT-N66U router and a TpLink WA901ND which I planned to use as an access point for customers and employees. The business intranet is on a LAN connected over CAT5es. The problem is I don't want our customers peeking into our network and using our resources. Turns out the AP firmware doesnt have the guest access feature. so my setup is bunk. Is it enough to password secure the file sharing and printers for our workgroup through windows 7 or am I asking for trouble by leaving that AP open to the business network? What options do i have with the hardware I have?

Comment: sadly the community voted your WiFi APs off topic

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely do NOT want to just push forward as-is without addressing the very real security concerns.  Small businesses often compromise in areas like this because they view themselves as small targets.  The question isn't how much you imagine someone else has to gain, it's how much you have to lose.

That out of the way, it really shouldn't be too hard to get something reasonable.

In fact, unless I strongly misunderstand what you're trying to do, [it looks like the Asus unit supports what you need](http://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTN66U/specifications/) without involving the TP-Link at all.

If you need the coverage of a second AP, etc... that might be another story.

So key to understanding this is understanding the processes beneath it.  So "guest wifi" is more than just another SSID (typically).  I couldn't find detailed enough documentation on how the Asus implements it, but it *should* be a separate network to itself.  So something like this:

```
[modem]-------[asus]  
               |  |  
  {guest ssid}--  --{business ssid}
```

It *ought* to treat the two networks as wholly separate.   Different address space, etc...   This can be easily verified.

- Setup the first network (internal).
- Attach two PCs to the network and make sure that you can ping/access them from eachother.

  - Once you know that works when it *should*, you'll be able to know for sure if/when the AP starts blocking that traffic.
- Next, create the 2nd network(guest) and move one of the PCs to that network.
- Chances are different address spaces will be used (192.168.1.x vs. 192.168.10.x, or something).  Either way, go ahead and try to ping from the one to the other.  If it works, then it's not filtering properly.
- If it *Doesn't* work, you still need to double check something else.  Take the PC on the guest network and, instead of using DHCP, manually assign it a valid address in the range used by the first network (using the settings from the other PC as a template).  THEN try to access the other pc.  If *THAT* doesn't work you know that the AP is doing at the very least a reasonable job of segregating the traffic.

There's still other ways that it could be doing a poor job, but at this point you've certainly done your due diligence for a small business.  If you're handling HIPAA data or something, you need more than this, but if that's the case you need to stop right now and go hire a pro who's willing to take responsibility for ensuring you're up to code anyway, as there's simply too much at stake to screw around on your own.

Now, if the data sheet I linked to is wrong, or the Asus fails the above tests, you might need more hardware.  Remember, this is actually a big deal.  You want to offer your customers free wifi, and that's great.  Go ahead and ask them how comfortable with your OTHER customers accessing their account information on your network.  Probably not at all, right?  Last thing you need is some kid screwing around with his laptop in the parking lot, finding your network, and throwing all your customer's data up on on pastebin "for the lulz".

So this *NEEDS* to happen, and if the asus doesn't do what you need, you need a new router(or firewall).

Whether this new router/firewall also handles your WiFi and replaces the ASUS, or is just a router unto itself and you still allow the Asus and tp-link handle the wireless is up to you.

You'll either setup something like I described with the Asus above, or something like this:

```
[modem]---------------[new router]
                         |  |
 {internal ssid}----[asus]  [tp-link]----{guest ssid}
```

The key point here is that the router will actually be routing between three networks.  So where on the back of the Asus unit all the interfaces on the back are part of one network ('broadcast domain' in network speak), here each interface will be it's own network.  (That may not be the default, but it should absolutely be possible... verify this before purchasing).

So then your asus bridges your internal SSID to the internal network created by the New Router (NR).  The TP-Link bridges your guest SSID to the guest network created by NR.  NR is responsible for ensuring that traffic is not permitted between the two networks (and you are responsible for testing/verifying this).

There are more implementation details that may not be obvious, but this is long enough for here, and should be enough to at least tell you if you need more hardware.

one final caveat is that if the ASUS fails the above tests, you still might be able to get away with using it in the way I described using NR above, **IF** you can get it to treat the interfaces on the back as "routed" interfaces instead of "switched" interfaces, or at least will put all of them on a different network than the WiFi.  I didn't get the feeling it supports that based off of the documentation, but it's worth looking into.

Answer (score -1):

What you have is two multilayer (layer 3+) access points - one manufactured by Asus and the other by TP-link.  Both support multiple SSID's  ([link](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-WA901ND#fea)).

You simply need to configure 2 SSID's on the TP-link - one guest SSID with or without basic password, the other (inside/protected) SSID being secured with WPA and not broadcast/advertised is typical.

The TP-link AP does not appear to support trunking so the routing between SSID's (subnets inside-tp and guest-tp) is going to take place on the tp link AP itself.  Then you will have 2 separate SSID for the Asus and be sure the channels don't overlap.  Basically you have 2 separate AP's and 4 separate WiFi subnets.  The TP-Link plugs in to the Asus for Internet/wired network access.

You should get some Meraki AP's and your life would be much easier.